# Update values from one table in another

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery, inner-join

I have tables A,B and C. I need to select certain values from all rows in Table A and then for every row in A, I need to update values in Table B and Table C.

Pseudo Code would look like this:

```
 SELECT A1, A2, A3, A4 FROM Table A 
           UPDATE Table B SET B2=A2, B3=A3, B4=A4 WHERE B1 = A1;
           UPDATE Table C SET C2=A2, C3=A3, C4=A4 WHERE C1 = A1;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you would use two update statements:

```
update b
    set (b2, b3, b4) = (select a2, a3, a4 from a where a.a1 = b.b1);

update c
    set (c2, c3, c4) = (select a2, a3, a4 from a where a.a1 = c.b1);
```

Comment: What if table B has more rows than table A?

Comment: @0xdb. . . The rows that don't match will have their values set to `NULL`.  Your question doesn't specify what to do in that case, so it seems like reasonable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You need two update statements. You could use an inline view:

```
update (
    select a.a2, a.a3, a.a4 , b.b2, b.b3, b.b4
    from a
    inner join b on b.b1 = a.a1
) u
set u.b2 = u.a2, u.b3 = u.a3, u.b4 = u.a4
```

The upside is that this only updates matching rows - while, using the correlated subquery technique, you need to repeat the subquery in the `where` clause.

Another neat syntax that does what you want in Oracle is `merge`:

```
merge into b
using a on (a.a1 = b.a1)
when matched then update set b.b2 = a.a2, b.b3 = a.a3, b.b4 = a.a4;
```